# customize the intervals of a legend in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, legend

i am plotting a density map from a csv file using histogram2D, contourf and matplotlib .
Please take a look on my result :
[image]

so, my main request is ho to customize the intervals of my legend , i need to have just 5 intervals with a step of 0.8 for example, and when it comes to the interval > 2.5 i want it to be just on interval with the same color and labeled by " 2.5 and above .
here's the code i am using to customize my legend :

```
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Paired', 8)
cs = m.contourf(xi, yi, g, cmap = cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('la densite des impacts foudre',size=18)

# Set borders in the interval [0, 1]
bound = np.linspace(0, 1, 9)
# Preparing borders for the legend
bound_prep = np.round(bound * 7, 2)
# Creating 8 Patch instances
plt.legend([mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(b)) for b in bound[:-1]],
       ['{} - {}'.format(bound_prep[i], bound_prep[i+1] - 0.01) for i in range(8)], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,15)
plt.show()
```

So basically i need a legend similar to this one :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have problems understanding your desired outcome. You say you want to have 5 intervals, but already in the code you have 8 levels. Also if the interval is 0.8, you only get 3 and an eighth intervals up to 2.5. How should the colors from the intervals relate to the colors of the contour plot?

Comment: well apparently you're really understanding my desired outcome, so yeah i have 8 intervals but i need to manage in order to keep just 6 or 5 intervals with a step lower than 0.8 of course and the intervals up to 2.5 should be in one summarized interval called 2.5 and above and with a unique color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I now understood everything correctly. To me it would only make sense to use the exact same number of levels in the plot as shown in the legend.

Of course you can select the levels to use manually via the `levels` argument to `contourf`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x= np.linspace(-3,3)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = np.exp(-(X**2+Y**2))

levels = [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,1]
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("Paired")
colors=list(map(cmap, range(len(levels))))


fig,ax=plt.subplots()
cf = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels=levels, colors=colors )
fig.colorbar(cf)

handles = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=c) for c in colors]
labels = [u"de {} à {}".format(levels[i], levels[i+1]) for i in range(len(levels)-1)]
labels[-1] = "plus de {}".format(levels[-2])
ax.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: yeah that's what i was looking for, thank you so much for your help !